# Custom DAO for Thinkup Plugin

Tags: php, thinkup

When creating a plugin for the ThinkUp Framework, how am I "supposed" to create new data models?

That is, I want/need my plugin to read and write data from the database, so my instincts are to create a new DAO such that I could say

```
DAOFactory::getDAO('MycustomDAO')
```

However, as the class names are hard wired into the DAOFactory, the above results in a "No DAO mapping defined for" exception being thrown.  Is it appropriate in my plugin to do something like the following?

```
DAOFactory::dao_mapping['MycustomDAO']['mysql'] = 'MycustomMysqlDAO';
```

If so, where should this wiring code live?  If not, what's "the right" way to setup a data model in a Thinkup plugin?  To be clear, I can think of a half dozen ways this could be done, but I'm looking for "the right"/"intended" way. I've looked over the documentation and the shipping code and can't find any examples of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Is [this library](https://github.com/ginatrapani/ThinkUp/) the one that you're talking about?